# Can linear regression be improved by data without targets?

Tags: linear-model, missing-data

I have a standard data set for linear regression (`X` - 2D array with values of features and `Y` - the corresponding 1D array with targets). I can use this data set to perform a standard linear regression.

Now we modify the setting slightly, namely we say that many targets are not available. In other words, for some features-vectors we have values of targets and for same feature-vectors we don't. For example:

```
1.2 0.4 3.5 -> 1.4
0.7 2.4 5.7 -> NaN
...
7.8 9.4 0.2 -> 3.9
2.7 6.6 8.7 -> 2.7
3.3 4.3 5.3 -> NaN
```

As you can see, some targets are missing. A simple approach would be just to remove all the rows (data points) for which targets are not present.

However, if we look at analytical solution for linear regression:

$
C = (X^T \cdot X)^{-1} \cdot X^T \cdot Y = \frac{X^T \cdot Y}{X^T \cdot X}
$

we see that the first term ($X^T \cdot X$) is calculated without targets, so I thought that the complete X can be used (even those rows, that do not have any targets).

Of course we should first introduce a normalization in the nominator and denominator to count for the fact that in dot products we have different number of summation. For example if means of features and targets are equal to zero (we can always get it). In nominator we would just have covariance between features and target and in denominator we would have covariance matrix between features.

**ADDED:**

To make it more precise, I would use the following solution:

$
C = (X^T \cdot X)^{-1} \cdot X^T_{small} \cdot Y_{small} \cdot \frac{N}{N_{small}} 
$

Where "small" indicate cases where target is present.

**Target is absent really by chance. There are not systematic differences between the statistics of features with and without the targets.**

Comment: I am skeptical about any benefits because before any normalization is done your method is equivalent to setting NaN to zero. And if one just puts NaN to zero and then normalize it afterwards it seems more efficient and less complicated to start of by considering putting other values of NaN to begin with.

Comment: You don't explain the mechanism driving the NaNs, an important piece of your puzzle. Why are they missing?

Comment: Just a minor note, NaN means ‘not a number’ which is different from being missing.

Comment: @utobi, in my case missing values are represented by NaN.

Comment: Pairwise deletion seems what you are considering https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-simplesolutions.html 1.3.2

Comment: I'm not sure this will really make any difference with linear regression, but (esp. if you are willing to widen your candidate model class(es)) in principle (self-)distillation on unlabelled data is something that is known to be helpful for some models (e.g. self-distillation of neural networks on unlabelled data, distilling an ensemble of multiple models into a single model on unlabelled data etc.). However, this usually needs a lot more unlabelled than labelled data. As you already allude to, if the data are missing in an (even slightly) systematic fashion, things get much more complicated.

Comment: Doesn't this boil down to a Heckman-type selection bias question? e.g., here https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-019-0840-7 Various alternative model specifications are considered.

Answer (score 0):

In the analytical solution for linear regression `C = ...`, you cannot just change the first two occurrences of `X` to be something different than the third occurrence of `X`. Because then `C = ...` will no longer be the analytical solution for linear regression.

So the answer is "no".

Comment: I do not do this.

Comment: I perform a normalization. In the nominator I have covariance between features and the target in the nominator I have covariance between features. I just estimate these two object with different number of observations.

Comment: OP consider the case y=x

Comment: How y can be equal to x? y is a number and x is a vector.

Comment: Consider univariate case

Comment: When you derive the solution for linear regression, C=..., you start by writing down an equation involving X and Y. In this equation X are the features _corresponding_ to the target data Y. Then there is some algebra and you arrive at C=... 
Then C will only remain the valid solution as long as all X stay the same as in the equation you started the derivation with.

Comment: @ernstkl, it is the case, if we want to find the linear function on features that minimizes the squared deviation between predictions and target. But what I want is a more accurate estimation of the coefficients of the linear function that with higher probability will give better results on out-of-sample.

Comment: @ernstkl, I do not "just change". I replace one thing by another one and there is a logic behind this replacement. I replace a less accurate estimation of the covariance matrix by a more accurate estimation of the covariance matrix.

Comment: $
C = (X^T \cdot X)^{-1}
$
is not an estimate of a population covariance matrix. There is no assumption made about a population distribution in the derivation of ordinary linear regression. That term is just the covariance matrix of the data used.

As such, ordinary linear regression gives you a consistent estimate of the coefficients in some sense.

Comment: In a previous comment you said that you want a more accurate estimation _in the sense_ that it will give better results on out-of-sample data.

So you would need to define what the distribution of out-of-sample data would be, and start with a derivation from there.